# How to set random number to random label

Tags: c#, random

i have int array with 9 numbers and i want to set a random number to a random label, (4 labels). at button click add next random number to next label so i have this code :

```
        int[] CardDeck = new int[9] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

        Random RandomCard = new Random();
        int randomIndex = RandomCard.Next(0, CardDeck.Length);
        int randomNumber = CardDeck[randomIndex];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(L1.Text))
        {
            L1.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(L2.Text) && Convert.ToInt32(L1.Text) > 0)
        {
            L2.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber);
        }
```

but something is wrong it sets same numbers to two labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using the same `randomNumber` variable.

You should generate another random number for the remaining label.

```
int randomLabel1 = CardDeck[RandomCard.Next(0, CardDeck.Length)];
int randomLabel2 = CardDeck[RandomCard.Next(0, CardDeck.Length)];
```

Then you should use these two variables with the labels accordingly.

Please note that this approach does not guarantee unique random numbers. Same numbers for both labels may occur.

**PS**: You can also use the same `randomNumber` to store a new random number, but remember to do it **AFTER** setting the first label:

```
int randomNumber = CardDeck[RandomCard.Next(0, CardDeck.Length)];
//Set first label
randomNumber = CardDeck[RandomCard.Next(0, CardDeck.Length)];
//Set second label
```